# Veracode CWE ID 259

Tags: session, credentials, veracode

Getting CWE ID 259 flaw in the below code in session.setAttribute line

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
    throws ServletException, IOException {

    HttpSession session = req.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("resetPassword", "Gets are not accepted.");
    this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("pwReset.jsp").forward(req, resp);    
}
```

Need help on fixing this.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you have to understand that code analysis tools like VeraCode might give false positive & you might have to take exceptions from security team ( and there might not necessarily be a code fix ) for some of the flags.

CWE ID 259 is all about hard coding of raw credential information like passwords in code & that is a very bad coding practice.

For your case , `session.setAttribute("resetPassword", "Gets are not accepted.");` , how does VeraCode know that you are hard coding  a raw password ?

Most likely, since you named attribute as `resetPassword` .

So hack fix would be to change this attribute name to not resemble to word **password** but even after this fix, for all practical purposes , vulnerability would still be there.

Permanent fix would be to either hardcode encoded / encrypted password in code or move hard coding of password from code & utilize some other secure mechanism to get reset password info.

Please read **Potential Mitigations** sections at - [CWE-259: Use of Hard-coded Password](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/259.html)